# eshop on Web ASP.Net core sample webapplication works with Kestrel (dotnet run) but can't be deployed in IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis, kestrel-http-server

I used visual studio 2022 to build eshopOnWeb ASP.Net core app (https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnWeb). It can run in VStudio as well as "dotnet run" command but when I deployed it in IIS using each of the options available in publish dialog, it doesn't work.IIS always came back with "HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden" error. If I enabled directory browsing, it will show deployed directories like a file share.

Apparently, it works with Kestrel but not with IIS.

My system configuration is Win Server 2019 with .Net 6.0 web-deploy installed. Appreciate any tips.

Comment: Did you set the Default Document in IIS for your website? The Default Document is the file served by the web server when the client does not specify a specific file in the URL. By default, the web server software will recognize the file name. Assuming your site should use home.html as the default document, you need to add it.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/developer/webapps/iis/health-diagnostic-performance/http-403-14-forbidden-webpage

Comment: As it is a .net app, I don't think we need to have a default document like index.html etc. By right it is an application runs by the Kestrel, which is in turned call by IIS (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=windows).

Comment: 403.14 indicates that wrong URLs were used when you tried to navigate to the deployed web app on IIS. So, when asking such questions around, show the actual error page so that others know what URL you were testing.

Comment: After restarting everything from the scratch, I am now stuck with the following error:

Comment: Hi Lex - thanks for looking into the issues. Finally I figured out that it might be an issue with database access. I used in memory database as in the documentation and it works. Just to add the following to the appsettings.json.
  "UseOnlyInMemoryDatabase": true,
The case is closed and thanks once again.